# Angular ngClass trigger change detection error when binded to ngModel validation

Tags: forms, angular

I'm trying to set the color of a label in Angular 2 depending on its email-validation like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" email #currentEmail="ngModel" [ngClass]="currentEmail.invalid ? 'error' : 'none'">
```

It works as expected on my page, however in Visual Studio Code I get the following error message:

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'error'. Current value: 'none'.

So my questions are:

1. Why does this message show up?
2. Whats the right approach to do this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why does this message show up?

You can find a good explaination of why in [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005#issuecomment-165905348)

> This is not a bug, it's a feature of dev mode working as intended. Calling enableProdMode( ) - when bootstrapping the app prevents the exception from being thrown.
>
> That said, it's being thrown for good reason: In short, after every round of change detection, dev mode immediately performs a second round to verify that no bindings have changed since the end of the first, as this would indicate that changes are being caused by change detection itself.
>
> In your plunk, you have the binding [attr.spinner]=isLoading, and isLoading changes as a result of your call to this.load(), which occurs when ngAfterViewInit is fired, which happens as a part of the initial change detection turn. That in itself isn't problematic though - the problem is that this.load() changes a binding but does not trigger a new round of change detection, which means that this binding will not be updated until some future round of change detection.

### Whats the right approach to do this task?

Simply replace `[ngClass]` with `[class]`. I don't know why, but when trying to reproduce your issue in a plunker, I found out that `[class]` does not trigger the error.

### Edit : use `ng-invalid` class

You can also style your element based on the angular class `ng-invalid`.

See [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/OYTawOd3MtAb3yqO4M4g?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much, changing from [ngClass] to [class] solved the problem.

Comment: There is existing issues on the Angular github repo, about `ngClass` acting werdly with the changeDetector. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14189 or https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12789